# GitHub Pages with repos as links

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm just a regular user on GitHub.  I don't have an enterprise or anything like that.  I was wondering can I still create a `https://myusername.github.io/` page like a blog or portfolio, and can that page contain links to individual repo github pages like `https://myusername.github.io/myrepo1`  That way this can act like a portfolio website.

Is this possible?  I keep having issues with setting up the `https://myusername.github.io/` page but the repo-based url works fine and is easy to set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [User GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/) will contain markdown files which, in turn, can include any URL you want.

Incuding URLs referencing your other repositories.